# LoadError when installing rails on Mac(OS X 10.8.3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Start learning rails but have problem when installing Rails on Mac. My version is OS X 10.8.3 currently and the problem is as follows:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:230:in `activate': can't activate rack (~> 1.4.5, runtime) for ["actionpack-3.2.13", "railties-3.2.13"], already activated rack-1.5.2 for ["rack-ssl-1.3.3", "railties-3.2.13"] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:246:in `activate'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:245:in `each'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:245:in `activate'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:246:in `activate'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:245:in `each'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:245:in `activate'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1056:in `gem'
    from /usr/bin/rails:18
```

How to solve this problem and run rails correctly?

Comment: It's tough for me to tell from what you've listed, but perhaps your development environment doesn't have everything necessary for Rails? This blog post really helped me with installation:  (http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/)

Answer (score 2):

You were going to install Rails 3.2.13, which does not support Ruby 1.8.

"Rails 3.2 is the last one that supports Ruby 1.8. Ruby 1.8.6 and earlier are not supported, neither is version 1.9.1." -- http://rubyonrails.org/download

Instead of fixing this problem directly, I suggest you to spend a bit time learning RVM. Then use RVM to install proper version of Ruby and then Rails.

Comment: FYI:  RVM stands for "Ruby Version Manager".