# Installing ruby on rails mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, macos

I'm trying to install ruby on rails on my mac, after installing I get this error. Can anyone please tell me how to resolve this issue?

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:777:in `report_activate_error': RubyGem version error: rack(1.5.2 not ~> 1.4.5) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:211:in `activate'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:246:in `activate'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:245:in `each'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:245:in `activate'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:246:in `activate'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:245:in `each'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:245:in `activate'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1056:in `gem'
    from /usr/bin/rails:18
```

Comment: Well, the error message is telling you that something it's running wants version 1.4.X of rack (where X is 5 or greater), but that you have version 1.5.2 installed. You should include the command that you ran to produce this error, as well as any details about what you were actually trying to do.

Comment: I just created a new rails app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds as though this might be your problem: [LoadError when installing rails on Mac(OS X 10.8.3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15525081/loaderror-when-installing-rails-on-macos-x-10-8-3)

You're using Ruby 1.8 (as you can see in your stack trace), but probably trying to install Rails 3.2.13, which simply doesn't work - it's not supported any more.

As the the answer there said, you should go back and learn about/use RVM to install a newer version of Ruby.